# How to get number value from string in Robot framework (Browser library)

Tags: browser, automated-tests, robotframework, browser-automation

I will try to get a string from a button's id. It will be "username12", I need to get that 12 number value.
It will be stored using `get text` but thats string, I need number value.

Answer (score 0):

```
*** Variables ***
${username}                  333username12

*** Test Cases ***

Get Trailing Number From Username
    ${no}=    Get Trailing Number   ${username}
    Log To Console    no is set to "${no}"


*** Keywords ***
Get Trailing Number
  [Arguments]   ${username}
  ${return_value}   Set Variable    ${NONE}
  TRY
    # Get all trailing digits via regular expression and convert to integer
    ${return_value}=    Evaluate    int(re.search("\\d+$","${username}")[0])     modules=re
  EXCEPT
    Log To Console    No number found
  END

  RETURN    ${return_value}
```